# Loading a page using jquery and replacing the page content

Tags: jquery, html

I am loading a page using jquery so it will not refresh the page. What I want to do is when I click on a link, it will load a page into the current page. I can do this. The problem now is that when the new content is loaded, the link that loaded the content remains on the page. Is there a way to remove this link once the new content is loaded? I can do this with php but not with jquery. My codes are shown below:

**HTML (the link)**

```
<a href="#" id="lik1">Link1</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#lik1').click(function(){
        $('#target').load('example.php');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by adding a `complete` function that hides the element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#lik1').click(function(){
        $('#target').load('example.php', function(){
           $('#lik1').hide();
        });
    });
});
```

For more info, see **http://api.jquery.com/load/**.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks